# Select integer column as corresponding letter of the alphabet

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `int` column that contains values no larger than about 20. I want to select as its corresponding upper case letter of the alphabet:

```
1 = A
2 = B
3 = C
...
```

I don't care what happens after Z because the column doesn't contain larger values. Is there a simple way to do this with a SQL query, to convert to a single-byte character like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 64 to your integer and you have the ASCII value of the letter you want.

```
mysql> select CHAR(1+64);
+------------+
| CHAR(1+64) |
+------------+
| A          |
+------------+
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char

Comment: Thanks, this is how I'd do it in other programming languages. Couldn't find this function, I was looking for `CHR()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative specific to MySQL using `elt`

```
select elt(col,'A','B','C','D','E','F',...);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2dd6e0b0550d6fb5e16065c02fcd03b)**